# how can i make a callback function on Unity JS

Tags: socket.io, json.net, unityscript

I've decided to make a game with unity + node.js

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/socket.io-unity

trying to use this library with unityscript

here is my code, so far

```
#pragma strict

import System.Collections.Generic;
import UnityEngine.UI;
import Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

public class SocketIOScript extends MonoBehaviour {

    var _socket : Socket;

    function Start () {
        if(!_socket) {
            _socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000");
            _socket.On("connect", function(asd) {
                _socket.Emit("chat", "hello");
            });
            _socket.On("chat", function(data) {
                print(data.id);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

but this line

```
            _socket.On("chat", function(data) {
                print(data.id);
            });
```

gives that error

> Assets/SocketIOScript.js(24,52): BCE0019: 'id' is not a member of 'Object'.

and when i tried to see what is the type of "data"

```
print(typeof data);
```

it says

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
```

I don't know what to do. It took my whole yesterday, so i decided to ask here

btw here is c# version of what i'm trying to accomplish (from socket.io-unity demo)

```
    socket.On ("chat", (data) => {
        string str = data.ToString();

        ChatData chat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatData> (str);
        string strChatLog = "user#" + chat.id + ": " + chat.msg;
```

Comment: Does `print(data["id"])` work?  If not, what do you get when you do `print(data.toString())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that callback functions are same as javascript

and solved the problem by adding

```
import SimpleJSON;
```

and then

```
_socket.On("chat", function(param) {

    var data = JSON.Parse(param.ToString());

    print(data['id']);
    print(data['msg']);
```